# Problem to Type casting

Tags: java

I am using Bonita Api [Java docs(Bonita Api)](http://www.bonitasoft.org/docs/javadoc/bpm_engine/5.2/) to get the instanceUUID of process and get the instanceUUID of type ProcessInstanceUUID.using getValue(), i am convert the object value in string and send another java class where i want to typecast String into ProcessInstanceUUID class object type.

it is possible,if possible please give me some idea to solve this problem.

```
ProcessInstanceUUID instanceUUID = this.getProcessInstanceUUID();
instanceUUIDValue = instanceUUID.getValue();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API:

```
ProcessInstanceUUID instanceUUID = this.getProcessInstanceUUID()
String instanceUUIDValue = instanceUUID.getValue();
ProcessInstanceUUID newUUID = new ProcessInstanceUUID(instanceUUIDValue);
```

As @Nivas said, this is **not** typecasting. Here is an example of type casting:

```
Object obj1 = "Hello World"; // obj1 is in fact a String
Object obj2 = new Integer(2); // obj2 is an Integer
String myString1 = (String) obj1; // explicitly type cast an Object to String
// The next statement will throw an exception at runtime because obj2 is not a String
String myString2 = (String) obj2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert the object to string, and reconvert it back to ProcessInstanceUUID object?

You can pass the ProcessInstanceUUID object itself.

BTW, typecasting is not what you think. It is **not** a mechanism to convert from *any* object type *any other* object.